# Extracting data from social media networks

Tags: facebook, twitter, youtube, extract

I am trying to create a Web application which will be able to analyze social media profiles. The social networking sites I want to analyze are Facebook, Twitter and YouTube.

I would like to use Data Extraction tool APIs as my back-end. Many of the tools I have found are either expensive or do not work.

I have researched on the Facebook, Twitter and YouTube API among others such as NodeXL.

Would anyone suggest any free available APIs which I could use please? Preferably ones which would not be too difficult to implement.

Comment: The only way to get data from Facebook is our Graph API and you can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter REST API https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Facebook Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Youtube API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

These are the publicly available API's you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tiny's answer could answer your question.

But I have another advice if you are asking how to extract data from social networks. You could try some web scraping tools to do that. Most of web scraping tools like [Octoparse](http://www.octoparse.com/) enable you to log in the targeted social network and extract data from these social networks.
If you are interested, you could refer to [Top 30 Free Web Scraping Software](http://www.octoparse.com/blog/top-30-free-web-scraping-software/) to learn more.

Answer (score -2):

There are many tools in the market. A social media scraper is a web scraping technology that pulls data from social media platforms automatically. They include blogs, wikis, and news sites, as well as social networking sites like Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, LinkedIn, and others.

Comment: The right thing to do in an answer is to provide *specific* examples of tools that the OP can use.